# Failed Yosemite TimeMachine "Use Drive (with Encryption)" renders drive unmountable on reboot

Tags: macos, disk-encryption, hard-drive-recovery, disk-utility, hfs+

I turned on TimeMachine and told it to use my Drobo volume for backups, and checked the box for encryption.  It thought about it for a few minutes and then bailed with an error stating that it couldn't turn on encryption (I don't have specifics, unfortunately).

I then just turned on TimeMachine without encryption and it worked fine.  Everything seemed normal until I rebooted ... Yosemite is unable to mount the Drobo, and Disk Utility doesn't provide any relief

```
## rebuildMasterList ##
**********
Disk:   disk0 (APPLE HDD HTS541010A9E662 Media) - 0x7fa6cbe1a860
    Partition:  disk0s1 (EFI) - 0x7fa6cbf544d0
    Partition:  disk0s2 (Macintosh HD)    [* boot volume] - 0x7fa6cbe1af60
    Partition:  disk0s3 (Recovery HD) - 0x7fa6cbf54850
Disk:   disk1 (Drobo) - 0x7fa6cbe1abe0
    Partition:  disk1s1 (EFI) - 0x7fa6cbf55320
    Partition:  disk1s2 (disk1s2) - 0x7fa6cbd221c0
    Partition:  disk1s3 (Boot OS X) - 0x7fa6cbc207f0


Verify and Repair volume “disk1s2”
Starting repair tool: 
repairError:  Some information was unavailable during an internal lookup. - -69808
Error: Some information was unavailable during an internal lookup.

Disk Utility stopped repairing “disk1s2”: Some information was unavailable during an internal lookup.


mac:~ admin$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            999.3 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *17.6 TB    disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         17.6 TB    disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk1s3
```

So it looks like the stupid encryption thing didn't actually turn on encryption, but left the partition type as CoreStorage??  This is complicated by the fact that diskUtil's coreStorage tool doesn't work with it at all.

```
$ diskutil core storage list
No CoreStorage logical volume groups found

$ diskutil coreStorage info /dev/disk1
/dev/disk1 is not a CoreStorage disk


$ diskutil info /dev/disk1
   Device Identifier:        disk1
   Device Node:              /dev/disk1
   Part of Whole:            disk1
   Device / Media Name:      Drobo

   Volume Name:              Not applicable (no file system)

   Mounted:                  Not applicable (no file system)

   File System:              None

   Content (IOContent):      GUID_partition_scheme
   OS Can Be Installed:      No
   Media Type:               Generic
   Protocol:                 FireWire
   SMART Status:             Not Supported

   Total Size:               17.6 TB (17592186044416 Bytes) (exactly 34359738368 512-Byte-Units)
   Volume Free Space:        Not applicable (no file system)
   Device Block Size:        512 Bytes

   Read-Only Media:          No
   Read-Only Volume:         Not applicable (no file system)
   Ejectable:                Yes

   Whole:                    Yes
   Internal:                 No
   OS 9 Drivers:             No
   Low Level Format:         Not supported
```

With great promise, I purchased DiskWarrior 5 which won't even look at the drive because it's not mounted.

Then I tried Stellar Volume Optimizer which claims to repair busted volumes, but it won't touch it either because it says the logical volume is encrypted (even though DiskUtility suggests it isn't).

What's next?  Is there a way to forcibly change the partition type back to HFS+ journaled?  My suspicion is that it's just the partition type that's misleading everything else.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I believe is "don't do that". At least, don't turn on encryption unless it's a fresh drive with mostly nothing on it. Incrementally encrypting/decrypting a few files at a time as they're added or accessed is not a problem. But turning on encryption on a whim for a drive containing over a terra but of files?  Recipe for disaster.

Nothing fixed it without dats loss.